# Django-tastypie creating a URL hierarchy

Tags: django, tastypie

I'd like to create a URL hierarchy using Tastypie but am running into some errors. Here's how I'd like the hierarchy to work:

```
/recipe  
/recipe/ID  
/recipe/ID/spice  
/recipe/ID/spice/ID
```

I can't find out how to do this. When I set this up following the Tastypi instructions my URLs would be like this:

```
/recipe  
/recipe/ID  
/spice  
/spice/ID
```

If I change the resource_name for spice to "/recipe/spice" then I get a "**NotFound: Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type)**" error.

Any suggestions about what I could do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tastypie is meant to help implement a REST API, and thus by default only supports URLs that conform to REST practices. Namely, each URL should contain a resource name ('recipe' or 'spice') and optionally an identifier for that resource ('ID'). Anything outside of this breaks from REST practices and if you're not implementing a REST API you may want to re-consider whether or not you should be using Tastypie.

That being said, Tastypie does provide a ton of hooks for customizing things. For custom URLs, you'll want to define the method [override_urls](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.11/resources.html#override-urls) to map certain URLs to custom views and do some pre-processing before sending it to the regular dispatchers.

If possible, I'd recommend just using standard REST practices and break things up as separate 'recipe' and 'spice' resources. If you need to filter on recipes based on spices that are in them, 'spices' should be passed in as a GET parameter rather than part of the base URL. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Did a little more research on it and it makes sense now. I will stick with the restful way of doing it.